# javascript collapsing many spaces into one, like HTML? strange behavior

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering this weird behaviour and I don't really understand why.

I have a function to normalize strings:

```
function normalize_for_find(name) {
    return name
        .trim()
        .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
        .replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
}
```

Which if I execute in chrome console, I get `"&nbsp; "` transformed into two spaces, which is what I want:

```
normalize_for_find("MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g")
"MONKEY BISCUITS  200g"
```

[image]

But then when I use it in this method, it somehow transforms `"&nbsp; "` into only one space.

```
function find_by_name(elems, name) {
    name = normalize_for_find(name);
    return _.find(elems, function(e) {
        return name === normalize_for_find(e.name);
    });
}
```

Take a look at this debugging:

`name` starts as `"MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g"`

[image]

and then after the call to `normalize_for_find` it appears as `"MONKEY BISCUITS 200g"` (only one space)

[image]

I need it to be two spaces like when I execute from console.

Here is more info on watching each variable, which makes no sense to me at all!

[image]

Comment: This does not answer your question but you does transform `&nbsp;` into ONE space only. The second space is originally there. `"MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g"` got one `&nbsp;` and one space between `&nbsp;` and `200g`.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to make it more at that I want `"&nbsp; "` transformed into two spaces

Comment: I think it is just the debugger display problem. Even though you see 1 space in the `Watch` window, you would see 2 spaces if you `console.log()` it. Actually it does show 2 spaces in the `Scope` window under `Local`, while showing 1 space in `Watch`

Comment: true! if I log I see two spaces. But now it gets weirder. I log this: `console.log(name, normalize_for_find(e.name), name === normalize_for_find(e.name))` and get `MONKEY BISCUITS  200g MONKEY BISCUITS  200g false`. Why would the comparison fail?

Comment: because the outer `name` is not the same `name` varible as inside `normalize_for_find`.

Comment: my god! I swear there are two spaces before the first `200g` in the comment above, but it appears only one there too. Only in the first

Comment: @troy why wouldn't it be? It's not being shadowed by anything in that inner callback.

Comment: @troy f it were the outer name it should still be `MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g`

Comment: my bad, I got the wrong idea. what actually is `elems`? by running `find_by_name([{name:"MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g"}],"MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g")` I got `true`

Comment: @troy thanks for trying. the one inside elems should have 2 spaces, not `&nbsp;`,  and the one outside is correct with `&nbsp;`

Comment: I added more info on the variables in the question. I dont understand how the comparison gives false if they are two strings with the same length, and I ask char by char and they give the same

Comment: Why not you try to post a runnable code snippet here?

Comment: `find_by_name([{name:"MONKEY BISCUITS  200g"}],"MONKEY BISCUITS&nbsp; 200g")` => `true`

Comment: @Yong because if I execute the code by calling it in the chrome console, it works as expected. It fails with the real data inside my site

Comment: @troy yes! it works correctly for me too when I execute separately, but when inside the real deal it does not work :(

Comment: @troy How to check that?

Comment: We can better see what's wrong if you can provide us with a section of actual non-sensitive data together with related data-parsing functions. From what I see, something is definitely wrong in either your data or one of those functions.

Comment: @troy There is definitely something happening that makes the two strings different even though they have the same length and chars. I don't know if strings have encoding in javascript or what could be influencing this.

Comment: like `console.log([...yourString].map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0)))`. this code print every char's ASCII code. compare two array's member one by one and find out what's different

Comment: hooray! so the difference is that in `name` the `&nbsp;` got transformed into ascii code 32 (regular space) while in `e.name` that space is ascii code 160, alias "non breaking space". This explains why the debugger shows it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between both strings is that the original `e.name` contains a "non breaking space" char which is ascii code 160, while the `normalize_for_find` method inserts a regular space which is ascii code 32.

As suggested by another user, this can also be fixed by changing the normalize method to this:

```
function normalize_for_find(name) {
    var parsed = jQuery.parseHTML(name);
    if (!parsed || parsed.length == 0) return '';
    return parsed[0].data.trim();
}
```

(note that `jQuery.parseHTML(name)` will return null for `''`)

Comment: remember to check encoding when there are weird string problems :)